# BeautyTips - Refresh after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-4.0, beautytips

I'm using the BeautyTips jQuery plugin in a template column in my RadGrid to show additional information.

Everything is working well, but I have one issue:  After the user applies some changes and clicks the update button (which causes a partial page update), the BeautyTips plugin still shows the outdated info.

I've put a breakpoint on the code that loads the info it uses, and it is not hit after initally loading them; so BeautyTips is caching that result somewhere.

Is anybody aware of a way I can force those to refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; I figured this one out:

There's an option in BeautyTips called `ajaxCache` which will cache the results of ajax calls.

Setting this to false (the default is true) solved my problem.